# Where can I get Beijing GIS data?

Tags: data, china

I was meandering so many places to find GIS data for Beijing, but it seems like I cannot get to any useful resources.  Though I did get at least road, water shapefiles and outline of Beijing city.

Specifically, **what I need is buildings and parcel (lots) maps** to investigate site analysis in the Beijing CBD area.

Comment: Try asking this question on [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), perhaps they have better ideas.

Answer (score 3):

The Beijing extract of OSM data, which doesn't appear to have parcels or buildings, is available here: http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Beijing/

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'Open Street Map' data..

http://planet.openstreetmap.org/

Use the 'single shapefile' link to obtain data...

Comment: Your answer would be much more helpful if it indicated how once could download the required data from OSM. Just giving a link to the OSM website isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I can not add a comment. search in this lab website https://www.beijingcitylab.com/data-released-1/external-data/ for your desired data